# Javascript error : message, stack undefinded, code 7

Tags: javascript, exception

I expect, any caught exception in Javascript delivers a message and a stack.

```
try {
   doSomething();
} catch(e) {
  alert(e.message);alert(e.stack);alert(JSON.stringify(e));
}
```

However, what I get is two alerts with the string `undefined` and one `{ code: 7 }`

What could be responsible for that?

---

```
function doSomething() {
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
 reader.onload = function(event) {
   var result = event.target.result;
   var jqxhr = $.post(url, { data: result}, function(data) {  alert(data); });
 }                                          
}
```

Comment: That should work in recent browsers for intrinsic exceptions, Does `doSomething` have its own exception mechanic? E.g. `throw {code: 7};` as the built-in `Error` object has no `code` property.

Comment: doSomething() is a little complex, but narrowed down it looks like this (see main section)

Answer (score 0):

found it out myself:

```
                            directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries){
                                for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {

                                    //NOT here!! 
                                    //var reader = new FileReader();

                                    var entry = entries[i];                                         
                                    entry.file(function(file){

                                            //here!! 
                                            var reader = new FileReader();

                                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                                            reader.onload = function(){}
                                    });

                                }
                            });
```